# How to pass column data to dropdown list

Tags: laravel

I have categories table, there are columns id and category_name, how can I pass only data without column name please check screenshot below, 
so I want like there will be dropdown with select option, when I will select specific category_name, it will save its id to the database, example if I select category "sports" it will take id "1", please help me based on Laravel

Here is my controller

```
    public function create()
    {


        $categories = Category::all('category_name');       
        $data = array(
            'weekdays' => [
                'Monday'=>[
                    '2p.m',
                    '3p.m'
                ],
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday'
            ],
            'categories' => $categories
        );
        return view('pages.clubs.create_club')->with($data);
    }
```

My View

```
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('categories', 'Select Category')}}
            {{Form::select('categories',$categories,null,array('multiple'=>'multiple','name'=>'categories[]'))}}
        </div>
```

Screenshot :
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pluck to get values in the drop-down,

```
 $categories = Category::pluck('category_name','id');
```

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

On your **Controller:**

```
$categories = Category::pluck('category_name','id'); 
return view('pages.clubs.create_club', compact('categories'));
```

On your **Blade:**

```
<div class="form-group">
 {{Form::label('categories', 'Select Category')}}
 {{Form::select('categories[]',$categories,null,['multiple'=>'multiple']))}}
</div>
```

Please note that you do not need the `'name'=>'categories[]'` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
   In controller use this method..if multiple values have to be sent to the 
   view,
   $categories=DB::table('categories')->get();
   $time=DB::table('times')->get();
   $params = [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'time' => $time,
            ];
    return view('pages.clubs.create_club')->with($params);
   In view
      <label>Select Category:</label>
      @foreach($categories as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->category_name }}</option>
      @endforeach</select>
      <label>Week Days:</label>
      @foreach($time as $item)
      <option value="{{ $item->value }}">{{ $item->value }}</option>
      @endforeach</select>
```